# IdentityServer3 PublicOrigin and IssuerUri Difference and Usage in IdentityServerOptions

Tags: identityserver3, identityserver4

I got some issue when deploying to IIS. Apparently the client uses reverse proxy and all of the OpenId configuration disco showing IP address instead of their domain name. `PublicOrigin` solves my problem. However, I still don't understand the different between,

```
PublicOrigin
```

and

```
IssuerUri
```

Example in:

```
var options = new IdentityServerOptions
{
    PublicOrigin = "https://myids/project1/",
    IssuerUri = "https://myids/project1/",
    ...
}
```

I can see from the disco showing changes as well if both value updated respectively, i.e.;

```
{
  "issuer": "https://myids/project1/",
  "jwks_uri": "https://myids/project1/.well-known/jwks",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/endsession",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://myids/project1/connect/checksession",
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/revocation",
  "introspection_endpoint": "https://myids/project1/connect/introspect",
  ...
}
```

and why not just make it the same as IssuerUri. I have read the documentation on this. Technically is just a description of the properties. I would like to understand more.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**`IssuerUri` is unique identifier of the authorization server**. Value of this property is embedded into ID tokens in the `iss` property and it is during token validation.

On the other side, **`PublicOrigin` is just a public URI of the server**. If the server is behind reverse proxy, then without this hint it would advertise private URI in OpenID Connect metadata (`.well-known/openid-configuration`).

**Why not have just single property?** OpenID Connect specification ([§ 16.15. Issuer Identifier](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IssuerIdentifier)) supports multiple issuers residing on the same host and port. However the same section in specification recommends to host only a single issuer per host and port (i.e. single-tenant).

**When would you use multi-tenant architecture?** Suppose you want to build and sell your own Authentication-as-a-Service. Now you have two options - assign dedicated URI (`PublicOrigin`) to each of your customers or use single `PublicOrigin` with dedicated `IssuerUri` for each customer.